# Sum of 2 Standard Guassian variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that when X and Y are independent and normally distributed, then X+Y is also Normally distributed. But now, let's remove the hypothesis of Independence. Can anyone please prove or provide a counter example for the following statement

When $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian random variables (on the same probability space) then $X+Y$ is also Gaussian.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: $Z$ has standard normal distribution. If $|Z|<1$ then $X=Y=Z$ otherwise $X=Z,Y=-Z$. Both $X$ and $Y$ have standard normal distributions but $X+Y$ lies between -1 and 1.

Comment: If all that is needed is that X + Y lie between -1 and 1 for this to be a counterexample, then you could just take X to be N(0,1) and Y to be -X. Then X + Y = 0, which is between -1 and 1. But a degenerate at 0 can be seen as a normal with zero variance. So the last sentence is not very well-written in my opinion.

Also, following your construction, if Z is realized to say 0.75, then |Z|<1, and thus X = Y = Z = 0.75. Then X + Y = 0.75 + 0.75 = 1.5, which is not in [-1,1]. So, I think the support of X+Y in your example is [-2,2].